# NLTK - Download all nltk data except corpara from command line without Downloader UI

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus, nltk-trainer

We can download all nltk data using:

```
> import nltk
> nltk.download('all')
```

Or specific data using:

```
> nltk.download('punkt')
> nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')
```

But I want to download all data except 'corpara' files, 
for example -  all chunkers, grammers, models, stemmers, taggers, tokenizers, etc

is there any way to do so without Downloader UI? something like,

```
> nltk.download('all-taggers')
```

Comment: i think i looked into this at some point, and couldn't find a way to do it. the source code is [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/downloader.html), for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List all corpora ids and set `_status_cache[pkg.id] = 'installed'`.

It will set status value for all corpora as **'installed'** and corpora packages will be skipped when we use `nltk.download()`.

Instead of downloading all corpora and models, if you're unsure of which corpora/package you need, use `nltk.download('popular')`.

```
import nltk

dwlr = nltk.downloader.Downloader()

for pkg in dwlr.corpora():
    dwlr._status_cache[pkg.id] = 'installed'

dwlr.download('popular')
```

To download all packages of specific folder.

```
import nltk

dwlr = nltk.downloader.Downloader()

# chunkers, corpora, grammars, help, misc, 
# models, sentiment, stemmers, taggers, tokenizers
for pkg in dwlr.packages():
    if pkg.subdir== 'taggers':
        dwlr.download(pkg.id)
```